# Success but no Ethereum

Tags: ether, metamask

Tried sending some Eth from MetaMask to Huobi. It left and says it was a success but the eth not showing up. Checked the address 5 times and all good so have I missed something simple here? Been over 3hrs!!

Cheers

Comment: Do you have the transaction id?

Comment: All good guys! Just took a lazy 7hrs!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to contact Huobi support for this issue.